# Jquery - switch && not working?

Tags: jquery, switch-statement

I am trying to control a hidden input value based on the value of 2 previous fields. I've had some success with a switch statement, but I just can't seem to get it to work exactly.  What I would like to have happen is to test if a user entered CA or NV in the field #state, if they did, AND they selected the option value auto, the #ins_link value will change to CA or NV(respectively).  What am I doing wrong here?  Here is what I am working with:

```
<input class="statefield isstate" name="state" id="state" maxlength="2" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();">

<select class="input_field_12em required" name="ins_type" id="ins_type">
                                            <option value="" selected="selected" >---Select Insurance Type---</option>

                    <option value="home">Home</option>
                    <option value="auto">Auto</option>
                    <option value="homeauto">Home + Auto</option>
                    <option value="renter">Renter</option>
                    <option value="buildingowner">Building Owner</option>
                    <option value="dwellingfire">Dwelling Fire</option>
                    <option value="commercial">Commercial</option>
                    <option value="agricultural">Agricultural</option>
                </select>       


$(function() {
    $('#ins_type').change(function() {
        switch (this.value) {
           case 'auto':
           if ($("#state[CA]" && "#ins_type[auto]"))
              $(".ins_link").val("CA"); 
              break;
            case 'auto':
           if ($("#state[NV]" && "#ins_type[auto]"))
              $(".ins_link").val("NV"); 
           default :
              $(".ins_link").val("summary");
           break; 
        }
    });
});

<input type="hidden" class="link ins_link" value="summary">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual way to solve your problem would be

```
$(function () {
    $('#ins_type').change(function() {
        if (this.value === "auto") {
            var state = $("#state").val();

            if (state === "CA" || state === "NV") {
                $(".ins_link").val(state);
            } else {
                $(".ins_link").val("summary");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Do you see how this code actually reflects your requirements?

- If `#ins_type`'s value is "auto":

  - If `#state`'s value is "CA" or "NV", set `.ins_link`'s value to the state selected.
  - Otherwise, set `.ins_link`'s value to "summary".

Your code structure should reflect your thought structure.

Comment: Thank you!  That helps me understand. Unfortunately now when I select an option other than auto, the .ins_link is not changed back to "summary", even though I do see that you put it in the code.  Any idea why?

Comment: Ah, well, follow the logic chain. The value of `.ins_link` gets set to `"summary"` in what cases? Only when `#ins_type`'s value is `"auto"` and `state` is not `"CA"` and not `"NV"`. To get the effect you want, you will need another `else` to handle the case when the value is _not_ `"auto"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
       if ($("#state[CA]" && "#ins_type[auto]"))
```

That's doing the logical AND of two strings, the result of which is then used as a selector for an element in your page. This will not work.

Your sample code doesn't show where/how you store the state information, but you'd want something more like this:

```
case 'auto':
    if ($('#state').val() == 'CA') {
        ... do california stuff ...
    }
    if ($('#state').val() == 'NV') {
        ... do nevada stuff ...
    }
    break;
```

Checking for the 'auto' selection again within the inner if() is redundant, as you've already forced it to be 'auto' with the `switch()`.

Comment: What he probably wants is `$("#state[CA],#ins_type[auto]").length`

Comment: @Kevin Peno: nope, that wouldn't work, because the `#state` element will never have an attribute named `CA`, so the attribute selector `[CA]` will never match.

Comment: @Domenic, *will never* or *shouldn't*?

Comment: @Kevin Peno: will never. I don't see `<input id="state" CA="something" />` in his code.

Comment: `#state[value='CA']` would work, assuming it's an input field and not a dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You have some misunderstandings of how JavaScript and jQuery work here.

`"#state[CA]"` is just a string, as is `"#ins_type[auto]"`

`"#state[CA]" && "#ins_type[auto]"` converts those strings to bools, then asks if they are both true. Only the empty string converts to false, so the logic is:

```
"#state[CA]" && "#ins_type[auto]" === true && true === true
```

Then you are wrapping that with a `$` function call, which just converts its arguments to a jQuery object. So

```
$("#state[CA]" && "#ins_type[auto]") === $(true) = $()
```

i.e. you just got the empty jQuery object, since you didn't pass a selector or a DOM element.

If you test any non-`null`, non-`undefined` object with `if`, it converts it to bool, so you get `if(true)`:

```
    if ($("#state[CA]" && "#ins_type[auto]"))
<=> if ($())
<=> if (true)
```

The same logic applies to your second `if` statement, so both `if` statements do nothing.